# JavaScript setTimeout Runs Twice

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to make a function that starts in exact intervals to keep stanble update rate. The problem is that it seems to execute in 2 channels. This is the log:

```
timeElapsed=141; lastDraw=1314040922291
timeElapsed=860; lastDraw=1314040923151
timeElapsed=141; lastDraw=1314040923292
timeElapsed=860; lastDraw=1314040924152
timeElapsed=141; lastDraw=1314040924293
timeElapsed=860; lastDraw=1314040925153
timeElapsed=141; lastDraw=1314040925294
timeElapsed=860; lastDraw=1314040926154
timeElapsed=141; lastDraw=1314040926295
timeElapsed=859; lastDraw=1314040927154
timeElapsed=143; lastDraw=1314040927297
timeElapsed=858; lastDraw=1314040928155
timeElapsed=143; lastDraw=1314040928298
timeElapsed=858; lastDraw=1314040929156
timeElapsed=142; lastDraw=1314040929298
```

First, I exectute my function using

```
drawTimer = setTimeout(function(){ draw() }, 1);
```

and the function looks like this:

```
var draw = function(){
    if(!running)
        return;

    var miliseconds = getCurrentMiliseconds();
    var timeElapsed = miliseconds - lastDraw;
    lastDraw = miliseconds;

    console.log("timeElapsed=" + timeElapsed + "; lastDraw=" + lastDraw);
    onDrawListener(timeElapsed);

    if(timeElapsed < timeLapse)
        miliseconds = timeLapse - timeElapsed;
    else
        miliseconds = 1;        

    drawTimer = setTimeout(function(){ draw() }, miliseconds);
}
```

It happens in both, Chrome and Firefox. Do you know what is it caused by? And... How to fix it?

P.S. Since everyone seems to be so confused about the *running* variable, here it is: it's a private parent object member that indicates whether the mechanism is still running or has stopped. It's set by other functions and is just there to make sure this function doesn't continue working after stop() is called.

-- update --
timeLapse is set to 1000 (1 time per seconds) and never changed again.

onDrawListener is set to this function:

```
function(timeElapsed){
        canvas.clear();

        moveSnake();

        if(snake.body[0] == food){
            food = getRandomFreePosition();
            ++snake.body.lenght;
        }


        drawBackground();
        drawFood();
        drawSnake();

    }
```

to explain it: canvas is kinda the engine that takes care of callbacks, key listening and also has a few functions. Other than that seems kinda self-explaining. they do nothing other than some int algorithms and drawing in the canvas.

-- Figured out --
I understood that I should calculate time spent for current function and not since the last one started. My old method worked not in 2 channels but rather in long-short-long-short-long-... delayes

Comment: What do you need drawTimer for?

Comment: Also, why are you not using `setInterval` in this situation? Unless you expect the execution of your iteration to be longer than the interval time, it could simplify things for you.

Comment: @Tejs He's can't use setInterval since he wants the interval to change each time (he recalculates `miliseconds` each time the function is called)

Comment: shouldnt it be if(running) return; ??

Comment: running is a a private member in a parent object that indicates that the mechanism is running. It's just there to make sure it stops the updating when it's not supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

first of all you dont set the running bool and also when you enter the function immediately do a on clearTimeout on drawTimer.

```
clearTimeout(drawTimer);
```

Comment: I set running but it's an outside way to stop this function from looping so it is set outside the function. But it's not the cause. I didn't know I have to clear timeout even when it has finished (called the function). That was my problem. Will mark this answer soon.

Comment: Akward thing happened. Firstly, when I added your code to my code and it worked as a charm but after writing a message I refreshed the browser and the double-run effect was back. WTF?

Comment: can you show what is onDrawListener and also what is timeLapse ?

Comment: Why use `clearTimeout()`? With the code as given the only way to get into the `draw()` function is via that timeout, and you can't clear a timeout that has already happened...

Answer (score 0):

In a loop like that, you should consider to write:

```
 if(timeElapsed >= AMOUNT_OF_TIME) 
{   
 // run code 
}
```